# Understanding peak repetitive surge current

Tags: datasheet, optoelectronics

I have moc3021 optocouplers.  The data sheet says it has a peak repetitive surge current rating of 1 amp, 120 pps.  I was hoping to use a microcontroller to control 24V .800A AC with this optocoupler.  I am assuming .800 is the rms, so the peak current would actually be 1.1A and too high for this device.  Am I understanding this correctly?

MOC3020 thru MOC3023 Series datasheet
https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/liteoninc/liteon-incmoc302x20series20201606

Comment: Try linking the data sheet. Also, if you have received useful answers to any of your previous questions, you should upvote. If you received an answer that gave you the information you needed, you should formally accept it. I mean, you have been a member for 4 years and you must have noticed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That device is not suitable to drive load, it can be used as another triac driver. 1 Amp is can be conducting for short time. That parameter gives you way to calculate resistor between output optotriac MOC3021 and triac gate. In case the triac turned on on voltage peak. For instance, triac commutate 220V, the peak is 315 V. Resistor min 330 Ohm( closest value). When triac on, MOC3021 output is shortened, so current run for short time. The chip body can dissipate only 300 mW, voltage drop on triac 1.7V,so 1 Amps is too much.

Comment: Can you tell me What MOC is?

Comment: Sorry, just shortened. It is MOC3021, optotriac, which you are trying to use. MOC3021- 3023  designed to work as  triac driver.

Comment: Ah, I forget about the voltage drop for triacs.   The chip probably would cook pretty quick, even though my peak current is probably around 300mA.